# Javascript: Arrays and For Loop Basics

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm new to javascript and have been trying to teach myself the basics.  I do have some experience with C++.

I came across this example in the source I'm using for studying and the for loop looks strange to me:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function ReadCookie()
{
   var allcookies = document.cookie;
   alert("All Cookies : " + allcookies );

   // Get all the cookies pairs in an array
   cookiearray  = allcookies.split(';');

   // Now take key value pair out of this array
   for(var i=0; i<cookiearray.length; i++){
      name = cookiearray[i].split('=')[0];
      value = cookiearray[i].split('=')[1];
      alert("Key is : " + name + " and Value is : " + value);
   }
}
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myform" action="">
<input type="button" value="Get Cookie" onclick="ReadCookie()"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Would someone mind explaining why there is a [0] and [1] near the end of these statements?

name = cookiearray[i].split('=')[0];
   value = cookiearray[i].split('=')[1];

Comment: Is it the loop or the `split` that is confusing you? If it's the split have a look what [the string method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) does return

Comment: The `split()` is indeed confusing because it is performed twice (for nothing).

Comment: The second time the split is done (which is in the for loop) is splitting a cookies Key/Value pairing into a usable array.  I suppose the data is of the form `Key=Value;Key=Value;Key=Value` as it would be for cookies...but the .split() function is used on strings so don't get caught up in the key/value discussion...that is not an inherent trait or (most) common use of .split().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A clearer way to write this statement is this:

```
 var parts = cookiearray[i].split('='),
     name = parts[0],
     value = parts[1];
```

Comment: You might better rename `split` (which of the two?) into a more descriptive version.

Answer (score 2):

That doesn't have anything to do with the for-loop itself. Split returns an array of tokens; the string is split up at the given delimiter. You're simply accessing the first and second tokens in this array.

Answer (score 1):

[`String.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) creates an array using the assigned delimiter (in this case '='). The `[0]` and `[1]` are selecting the first and second elements of the array respectively (Javascript array element indexes start at zero).

Answer (score 1):

Those are used to access the items in the arrays that you create.

It's more clear what they do, and also better for performance, if you put the array in a variable and access that. That way you don't have to create two identical arrays:

```
var cookie = cookiearray[i].split('=');
var name = cookie[0];
var value = cookie[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is splitting each cookie pair `key=value` into key (`[0]`) and value (`[1]`).

Comment: key [0] and nothing [1] of what?

Answer (score 0):

A for loop is an iterator.  You can sort of think of it like a counter, or stepping progression.  If you want to do something x number of times, then a for loop is your best friend.  The issue, when you are first learning, is figuring out how to use them effectively.

I'll give you a relevant and nonrelevant (simplified) example:

**Nonrelevant:**

```
// Increase the value of x and print the new value to the console 20 times.
var x = 6;

for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    x++;
    console.log("Value of x: " + x);
}
```

If you take a close look it's really rather logical.  You define an iteration variable `i`, tell it when to stop (`i < 20`...so stop if i = 20), how to progress with each iteration (`i++` or i + 1).

So the code will enter the loop when `i = 0`...it will add 1 to the value of `x` (x++), resulting in x = 7.  It does the same for each iteration, so when `i = 1`, x (7) + 1 = 8, so on and so forth until i = 20, then the code breaks out of the loop and continues on it's merry little way.  When it breaks we have just added 1 to `x` 20 times.  Since `x` used to equal 6, it now equals 26.

**Relevant:**

```
// Given array of length 10, print each element to the console

for (var i = 0; i < cookiearray.length; i++){
    console.log(cookiearray[i]);
}
```

So here the `for` loop is the same, it simply iterates until `i` equals the length (number of elements, in this case) of the array (so 10 times).  When `i = 0`, our code prints the element of the array at `cookiearray[0]`...when `i = 1` it prints `cookiearray[1]`...so on and so forth for the entirety of the array.

What may confuse you in the example is the split function.  Split returns an array.  So this line:

```
name = cookiearray[i].split('=')[0];
```

...actually means assign the first element of the new array created from splitting the cookiearray's element at position `i`.

Let's assume that `cookiearray[0] = "Hello=World"`.  When `i = 0`, our code splits the string "Hello=World" into a new array where the element at the 0 position is "Hello", it then assigns this to the local variable name.  So name = "Hello".